# SQL Server - how can I signal failure to the Job scheduler while using return codes to indicate state in stored procedure?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, error-handling, jobs

Today I ran into a problem where a stored procedure would have to be called both in a job and manually from other stored procedures and PHP api calls. The latter systems used the sp's return code to determine success, while the former only understands a set error level as failure.

To further complicate the issue, I had to wrap the sp in a try/catch because e-mails has to be sent and cleanup needs to be done in case of an error, making the sp report success even on failure to the job scheduler.

How can I make a design that would alert both systems of failure, seeing that both `THROW` AND `RETURN` immediately stops execution?

Example 1 - doesn't throw:

```
-- in catch block at end of sp
RETURN 1; -- execution stops here
THROW; -- throw back original error
```

Example 2 - doesn't return 1:

```
-- in catch block at end of sp
THROW; -- severity level is over 10, execution stops here
RETURN 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use `RAISERROR` (which is otherwise not recommended - [as per MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), "New applications should use `THROW` instead."). The reason is because errors under severity level 10 do not cause execution to stop or jump to the current catch block, it just sets `@@ERROR`, but `THROW` doesn't let you set the error severity - [it either uses 16 or the severity of the original error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#differences-between-raiserror-and-throw).

This way a code like this will both set the error level and return an integer:

```
-- inside the stored procedure
BEGIN TRY
  -- code
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  -- do cleanup
  -- code
  -- send e-mail about error
  -- code

  -- this is the important part for us
  DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ERROR ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, ERROR_NUMBER()) + ': ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
  -- 5 is under the thresold of 10, and with @msg we preserve info about the original error
  RAISERROR(@msg, 5, 0);
  RETURN 1;
END CATCH
```